# Split View like Settings

Tags: ipad

I have created a basic Split View and instead of loading a UIView on the right hand side, I have loaded a UITableView. The UITableView is made up of UITableViewCell's and what I want to do is when I click on the Cell, it loads up another UITableView for selection much like that in the iPad settings. However I cannot the UITableView to load after selection.

Any ideas how to achieve this? I've seen similiar questions and had a look at the apple site with uitableviews but haven't been able to solve the issue as they're geared towards iphone which doesn't have the split view.

On the didSelectRowAtIndexPath i've loaded it like so which other apps have done but to no avail.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        LevelTwoController *leveltwoController = [[LevelTwoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LevelTwoTableView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:leveltwoController animated:YES];

        [leveltwoController release];

    }
}
```

Another thing also is my leveltwoController is a UITableViewController and I just keep getting this import error literal-pointer@_*OBJC@*_cls_refs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main view that has the TableViewController needs to be controlled by a UINavigationController, and then you could push the subsequent views onto the view stack. My guess is your current implementation is having self.navigationController be nil so nothing is happening.

If you take a look at some of the basic xcode templates that use uinavigationcontroller's you should be able to figure out the proper path.

Comment: Thanks, i'll do some research on this route and hopefully get something working.